# Antlr error 'no viable alternative at character'

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I am using the Objective C grammar available [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1212699960054/ObjectiveC2ansi.g), and trying to parse this code:

```
int main()
{   
    int k=0;
}
```

this is an objective c code and it should get parsed but it is giving me the following errors when i call the function translation_unit.
errors are :

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at character 'main'
line 1:0 no viable alternative at character '('
line 1:0 no viable alternative at character ')'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes wrong because the rule `direct_declarator`:

```
direct_declarator 
 : identifier declarator_suffix*
 | '(' declarator ')' declarator_suffix* 
 ;
```

mandates that there should be something inside the parenthesis of the `main` function. But if you make that optional:

```
direct_declarator 
 : identifier declarator_suffix*
 | '(' declarator? ')' declarator_suffix* 
 ;
```

I am pretty sure other problems will arise. To be frank, that grammar is pretty lousy: I wouldn't use it if I were you. And no, I don't know of a better one :). Because the grammar is posted on the antlr-site does not mean it's a proper grammar. It's posted on the Wiki where anyone can post their work: keep that in mind when using stuff from it.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually this is my university project and we really don't have time to write my own objective c grammar. So we have to do this work using this grammar. And make this work for us..and thanks this is very helpful